# Why is it necessary to use = and avoid single-quotation marks when working with dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, key-value, keyvaluepair

```
def build_profile(first, last, **user_info):
    """Build a dictionary containing everything we know about a user."""
    profile = {}
    profile['first_name'] = first
    profile['last_name'] = last
    for key, value in user_info.items():
        profile[key] = value
    return profile

user_profile = build_profile('albert', 'einstein',
                             location = 'princeton',
                             field = 'physics')

print(user_profile)
```

In the `user_profile` variable I am not allowed (by Python) to write `'location':'princeton'` and `'field': 'physics'`. That's the structure of key-value-pairs, isn't it? Why can't I then use it, but am submitted by the IDLE to use `=`, and remove single-quotation marks which are in dictionaries used for assigning values.

Comment: As per your shared code, your function will throw an indentation error.

Comment: Are you mistaking a dict definition with a function call?

Comment: Briefly: you are calling a function, not creating a dictionary literal. The `**user_info` syntax tells Python to collect any extra named arguments _into_ a dictionary you can access within the function.

Comment: Thanks to all of you.